# How do I update my JTextField in JOptionPane in real time?

Tags: java, focus, joptionpane

I'm wanting to get rid of the text that is already set in my JTextField when I click inside the JTextField (focus on the JTextField).

Here's my code:

```
        if (newSerial.isFocusOwner())
        {
            newSerial.setText("");
        }
```

How do I get this code to run whilst I still have my JOptionPane.showMessageDialog running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but based on my interpretation of your question, you have a text field that you want to update while a JOptionPage message dialog is displayed.

JOptionPane dialogs block the Swing Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), so you can't update the UI while they are being displayed, unless you do it from a different thread (but that's not great - Swing components should be updated on the EDT).  If I read your question correctly, the easiest option might be to replace your JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...) can with a [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) that isn't a modal dialog, and therefore, won't block the EDT.